# Ajax save value from textbox to server

Tags: jquery, ajax, textbox, save

Just found out what Ajax is, and I want to build a simple Ajax/Jquery function that takes the value of a text-box and posts it to the server on a button click.. The button is a ui icon with a hover event attached to it which appends on key-press.. I've tried putting it together, but firebug console reads *syntax error*.. Please help..

```
    $(function () {
        $('.solo1').after('<span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon-disk ui-icon saveButton" title="Save" style="float:left; height:20px;" onclick="function save (value)"></span><br />')// ui icon
    .keypress(function() {
        $(this).next('.saveButton').show();//appends ui icon
    });
});


function save(value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/*ServerURL*/",
        type: "POST",
        data: '{ $("#craven1") : "' + value + '" }',
        data: "{ 'Id': " + $("#craven1").text() + ", 'content': " + $(".solo1").val() + "}",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
}
</script> 

<div id="featherbone">
<input class="solo1" id="craven1"/>
<input class="solo1" id="craven2"/>
<input class="solo1" id="craven3"/>
<input class="solo1" id="craven4"/>
<input class="solo1" id="craven5"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you get the error message when you click the UI button? In that case I think the syntax problem is in the HTML that is added after the .solo1 element, specifically in the onclick attribute:

```
$('.solo1').after('<span ... onclick="function save (value)"</span><br/>')
```

That should be:

```
$('.solo1').after('<span ... onclick="save (value)"</span><br/>')
```

Because you want the function save to be called (not defined, hence the removal of the keyword `function` from the `onclick` attribute).

But looking at your code and reading your description, I think you want the value of the input element adjacent to the button to be passed into the function?

In that case a better solution would be to first create the UI buttons and add the click handler to each later:

```
// Create button and then add it after each input
var button = $('<span ... ></span><br/>');
$('.solo1').after(button);

// Now that the buttons are created, find them and give each a click handler
$('.saveButton').click(function() {
  // Get value from the input element that this button was added after
  var value = $(this).prev().val();

  // Now call the save method with the value
  save(value);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/h78hw/

Comment: That is a problem, but he also isn't passing a value to his save function. Since he's already using jQuery, it'd be a much better idea to bind a click event handler to his span: `$("#spanId").click(function(){});`, or to just get the value of the textbox in the `save()` function. That is, rather than accepting `value` as a parameter, do a `var value = $("#textboxId").val();`.

Comment: @Josh: thanks, I had the same idea and was writing the code as you commented.

Answer (score 0):

Running JSLint on it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kp6hV/ reveals:

```
Error:
Problem at line 14 character 92: Duplicate member 'data'.
data: "{ 'Id': " + $("#craven1").text() + ", 'content': " + $(".solo1...

Problem at line 19 character 10: Extra comma.
},

Implied global: $ 1,2,4,10,14, console 18
```

That is, there is an extra comma after your 'success' function, and duplicate 'data' members, as I've commented above.

**Edit:** Error free:

```
function save(value) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/*ServerURL*/",
    type: "POST",
    //data: '{ $("#craven1") : "' + value + '" }', // Not sure what's going on here
    data: "{ 'Id': " + $("#craven1").text() + ", 'content': " + $(".solo1").val() + "}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```